# In ansible, how can I assign values to variable based on conditions?

Tags: ansible

I want to assign a value to a variable based on my env name. If env=e1, some variable name "var" should get the value as "x". If env=e2, "var" should get the value as "y".

Let me know your suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

Say you have an env var called FOO.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: "False"
  vars:
    my_env_var: "{{ lookup('env','FOO') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: "set e1"
      set_fact:
        my_ansible_var: "x"
      when: my_env_var == "e1"
    - name: "set e2"
      set_fact:
        my_ansible_var: "y"
      when: my_env_var == "e2"
```

You can now reference the {{ my_ansible_var }} value anywhere it is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Russ, one small question...

how can I define my env var FOO with e1 and e2  values?

Comment: Is there any way to call variables from var->main.yml to lookup. I am defining one variable as env_hn=e{{ ansible_hostname }} that will pick up the value e1 or e2 or e3, based on this variable value I want to assign values to few variables.

Comment: plus, can you give me some idea about this warning:

 [WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: "{{ env_hn }}" == "e2"

Comment: Monika: The warning tells you exactly what to do, remove the curly brackets around your variables in the "when" statement. See my example.